# When will my application be available in Ubuntu Software Center after publishing?

Tags: software-center, application-development, application-submission

I published my commercial software in Ubuntu Software Center already , the status has changed to 'Published' , but when I updated my software catalog by `apt-get update`, and  tried to search for my application , I got no record found.

Am I wrong here ?

**UPDATE**

[It's here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/cobra/)

Comment: Edit you question to include the name of the software and I'll see if it shows up for me...if you want.  The fellows that know for sure the roll-out time for this type of thing are usually on during the day US time.

Comment: @aking1012 , updated , can you check if it appears in software-center  it's available for 11.10

Comment: Any updates or new info? I'm not seeing Cobra in the USC... @DavidPlanella, do you have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should roll out immediately. That said, the Software Center uses an internal database for its commercial apps catalogue—not `apt-get`—and only updates it periodically. The app may take awhile to appear to clients.

You can force the Software Center to update its catalogue now with `sudo update-software-center`.